# auditctl - logging the CPU or identifier of pthread that invoked the system call

Tags: kernel, security, monitoring, system-calls, linux-audit

`auditctl` is a great utility for monitoring many things, such as executed system calls.

I would ideally like to know either the CPU or the POSIX thread that instantiated each recorded system call. In the log, I see:

```
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1561851079.335:286): arch=c000003e syscall=9 success=yes exit=140507297914880 a0=0 a1=1000 a2=3 a3=22 items=0 ppid=22818 pid=24283 auid=1005 uid=1005 gid=1005 euid=1005 suid=1005 fsuid=1005 egid=1005 sgid=1005 fsgid=1005 tty=pts0 ses=89 comm="my_benchmark" exe="my_benchmark" key=(null)
```

I don't think any of these do the trick, unless I'm missing something. Does anyone know if what I want is possible? Thanks.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, you might try [systemtap](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html-single/systemtap_beginners_guide/index) as in this [example](https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/03/06/stopped-mysql-tracing-back-signals-sent-mysql/) to find what killed a process.

Answer (score 1):

Piping your audit line through `ausearch -i` at least gets the most information out of it:

```bsh
» echo "type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1561851079.335:286): arch=c000003e syscall=9 success=yes exit=140507297914880 a0=0 a1=1000 a2=3 a3=22 items=0 ppid=22818 pid=24283 auid=1005 uid=1005 gid=1005 euid=1005 suid=1005 fsuid=1005 egid=1005 sgid=1005 fsgid=1005 tty=pts0 ses=89 comm="my_benchmark" exe="my_benchmark" key=(null)" | ausearch -i
----
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(06/30/2019 01:31:19.335:286) : arch=x86_64 syscall=mmap success=yes exit=140507297914880 a0=0x0 a1=0x1000 a2=PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE a3=MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS items=0 ppid=22818 pid=24283 auid=unknown(1005) uid=unknown(1005) gid=dovenull euid=unknown(1005) suid=unknown(1005) fsuid=unknown(1005) egid=dovenull sgid=dovenull fsgid=dovenull tty=pts0 ses=89 comm=my_benchmark exe=my_benchmark key=(null)
```

AFAIK, the thread ID is only recorded for kernel-generated syscalls and is then placed in the `pid` field. Reference: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security_guide/app-audit_reference under `pid`:

> The `pid` field semantics depend on the origin of the value in this field.
>   In fields generated from user-space, this field holds a process ID.
>   In fields generated by the kernel, this field holds a thread ID. The thread ID is equal to process ID for single-threaded processes. Note that the value of this thread ID is different from the values of pthread_t IDs used in user-space. For more information, see the gettid(2) man page.

I know no way of auditing thread ID's for user generated syscalls.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I ended up modifying the kernel source file `auditsc.c`, building and installing, simply to provide a TID in the log, as `audit_log_format(ab, "arch=%x syscall=%d tid=%d"...)` where the tid is given by an internal call to `task_pid_vnr(current)`. This does exactly what I need!

Comment: Wonderful! Isn't that just what we all love so much about open source software.